# MS Excel macro deleting duplicate rows and sum their values

Tags: excel, vbscript, unique, vba

I'm very briefly familiar with vba and I cannot work out how to amend the following script to make it do what I expect.

Basically I have 5 column excel. Column A are the values I would like to sum, providing that `B` **and** `C` **and** `D` **and** `E` are unique as a row.

I found the following script, which does nearly what I need:

```
Option Explicit

Sub RedoDataset()
Dim LastCol As Long
Dim LastRowData As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim Ctr As Long

Dim CompanyArr
Dim RowFoundArr
Dim SumArr
Dim Rng As Range
Dim SettingsArray(1 To 2) As Integer

On Error Resume Next
With Application
    SettingsArray(1) = .Calculation
    SettingsArray(2) = .ErrorCheckingOptions.BackgroundChecking
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ErrorCheckingOptions.BackgroundChecking = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With
On Error GoTo 0

With ThisWorkbook
    With .Sheets("Sheet1")
        LastRowData = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        LastCol = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, LastCol))

        .Columns(2).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
        CopyToRange:=.Cells(1, LastCol + 2), Unique:=True

        LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, LastCol + 2).End(xlUp).Row

        ReDim CompanyArr(1 To LastRow - 1)
        ReDim RowFoundArr(1 To LastRow - 1)
        ReDim SumArr(1 To LastRow - 1)

        For Ctr = 1 To LastRow - 1
            CompanyArr(Ctr) = .Cells(Ctr + 1, LastCol + 2)
            RowFoundArr(Ctr) = Application.Match(CompanyArr(Ctr), .Columns(2), 0)
            SumArr(Ctr) = Application.SumIf(.Columns(2), CompanyArr(Ctr), .Columns(1))
            .Cells(RowFoundArr(Ctr), 1) = SumArr(Ctr)

            Set Rng = Union(Rng, .Range(.Cells(RowFoundArr(Ctr), 1), _
            .Cells(RowFoundArr(Ctr), LastCol)))
        Next Ctr
        .Columns(LastCol + 2).Delete

        For Ctr = LastRowData To 2 Step -1
            If IsError(Application.Match(Ctr, RowFoundArr, 0)) Then
                .Rows(Ctr).Delete
            End If
        Next Ctr

    End With
End With

On Error Resume Next
With Application
    .Calculation = SettingsArray(1)
    .ErrorCheckingOptions.BackgroundChecking = SettingsArray(2)
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With
On Error GoTo 0


End Sub
```

this sums values of column A leaving column B unique. How do I extend this so not only B is unique, but condition is - `B` **and** `C` **and** `D` **and** `E` are unique in combination as a row.
Basically where the whole row is unique comparing to other, but not necessary each column contain only unique values:

```
    A    B      C      D      E
1  0.01  La    Ba     foo    boo
2  0.03  La    boo    foo    Ba
3  0.12  La    foo    Ba     boo
4  1.05  Ba    La     foo    boo
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code - it uses a different approach, that's more flexible:

```
Const cStrDelimiter As String = ";"

Sub Aggregate()
    Dim dic As Object
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim strCompound As String
    Dim varKey As Variant
    Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    'Store all unique combinations in a dictionary
    Set rng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
    While rng <> ""
        strCompound = fctStrCompound(rng.Offset(, 1).Resize(, 4))
        dic(strCompound) = dic(strCompound) + rng.Value
        Set rng = rng.Offset(1)
    Wend

    'Save all unique, aggregated elements in worksheet
    Set rng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("G1")
    For Each varKey In dic.Keys
        rng = dic(varKey)
        rng.Offset(, 1).Resize(, 4).Cells = Split(varKey, cStrDelimiter)
        Set rng = rng.Offset(1)
    Next
End Sub

Private Function fctStrCompound(rngSource As Range) As String
    Dim strTemp As String
    Dim rng As Range
    For Each rng In rngSource.Cells
        strTemp = strTemp & rng.Value & cStrDelimiter
    Next
    fctStrCompound = Left(strTemp, Len(strTemp) - Len(cStrDelimiter))
End Function
```

Comment: `dic(strCompound) = dic(strCompound) + rng.Value` is doing that

Comment: of course! sorry ! yes this ran like a charm and much faster than my original!!  thank you